# The argument "each" was registered with type "array", but is of type "MyDomain\myextension\Domain\Model\MyObject"

Tags: typo3

I get this error message but dont really understand it. Of course it is an object - i do have an irre relation to this object here. But normally the for each viewhelper should work with an object too ...

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/For.html

"The array or object to be iterated"

in debug output i can see the object and his items.

What i am doing wrong? 
TYPO3 8.7 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `MyObject` implements the `Traversable` interface, this won't work. The `f:for` viewhelper only supports array or `Traversable` objects.

Comment: The most used object for this is the result of a query: `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult`. Via the interface and \Iterator it implements the \Traversable interface.
You can't use a domain object as argument for the "for" VH. You can build an array of domain objects and use that for the "for" VH.

Comment: Shame on me ... i defined the connection between the both domain objects wrong ... 1:1 instead von 1:n with irre. You both brought me on my way :-) Thanks!